# Como editar HTML en Modo depuración Google Chrome

Tags: html, html5, google-chrome

Solicito el apoyo de todos, por favor ya que tengo este problema:

Necesito editar una página en Modo Depuración en el Google Chrome (Botón F12) ya que necesito alterar unas tags ( Ya que no tengo acceso al código fuente) para realizar un print de pantalla especifico.

El problema es que cuando entro en la TAG especifica, la página realiza un refresh automático, por lo tanto se cierra la TAG y no consigo editar la Tag que necesito en el Chrome ( F12 ).

Algún truco o forma de detener ese refresh para poder alterar la Tag Label for F12- google chrome? 
Observación: No tengo acceso al server.

Comment: tienes checkeado en console donde dice `Log XMLHttpRequest?`

Comment: Voy a verificar, dame unos 10 min

Comment: Verifique y encontre que no estaba con ticket, ahora tiene ticket el " Log XMLHttpRequest"

Comment: ApareceEN lOG XMLHttpRequest, 4 informaciones:
Tenant-Information Get      autorization.js:77
Tenant-Information Get      autorization.js:80
Tenant-Information Get      autorization.js:56
Tenant-Information Get      autorization.js:59